# Rails 4 creates duplicates when updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

I already tried whitelisting id, it doesn't help, it creates duplicates no matter what.

Model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, :social, :contact, :talent_parameter
```

The attributes I pass:

```
model_attributes = {
          talent_parameter_attributes: {
          },
          contact_attributes: {
              agency_link: base_url + href
          },
          social_attributes: {
          },
          address_attributes: {
          }
      }

      update_model(model, model_attributes)
```

The permissions I set:

```
  def self.update_model(model, attrs)
    params = ActionController::Parameters.new(model: attrs)
    model_params = params.require(:model)
    model_params = model_params.permit(
        :company,
        :age,
        :avatar,
        :gender,
        :contact_id,
        talent_features: [],
        talent_parameter_attributes: [:id, :weight_lbs, :dress, :shoe, :chest, :waist, :hips, :height_ft],
        contact_attributes: [:id, :agency_link],
        social_attributes: [:id]
    )

    model.update(model_params)
  end
```

I don't understand. Each time it creates another copy of `talent_parameter`, `contact`, `social` and `address`. What can be wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

Did you include **id** for models to be updated ? In [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), it states "For each hash that does not have an id key a new record will be instantiated"...

So try this:

```
model_attributes = {
      talent_parameter_attributes: {
      },
      contact_attributes: {
          id: 7,
          agency_link: base_url + href
      },
      social_attributes: {
      },
      address_attributes: {
      }
  }
```